# It there a pattern used to process a same function but assign the result to a different variable regarding to a different condition?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Say I have a code snippet like this

```
    if(string.Compare(isStandardFlag,"STANDARD",true)==0)
    {
        hearingID = centreSession.standardID;
        centreSession.standardOutcomeID 
            = disciplineSvc.SaveResultA(hearingID,OffenceID, Outcome);
        centreSession.standardOutcomeNoteID
            = disciplineSvc.SaveResultB(hearingID, txt1.Text, "ResultHearing"); 
    }
    else{
        hearingID = centreSession.noneStandardID;
        centreSession.noneStandardHearingOutcomeID
            = disciplineSvc.SaveResultA(hearingID,OffenceID, Outcome);
        centreSession.noneStandardHearingOutcomeNoteID
            = disciplineSvc.SaveResultB(hearingID, txt1.Text, , "ResultHearing"); 
    }
```

You can see the 'if' and 'else' do the same thing but just assign the result to different variables.

Is there a pattern I can refer to refactor the code?

Comment: What is the reason that you need to save the results in different properties?

Comment: @JeffVanzella it is a usercontrol been used in 2 different places on the same screen, the logic is very similar. I need 2 places to store their results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it looks like the `ID`, `OutcomeID` and `OutcomeNoteID` belong together, so I think it it makes sense to extract them into a separate class (though my naming of it is just a guess):

```
class Hearing
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }

    public int OutcomeID { get; private set; }

    public int OutcomeNoteID { get; private set; }

    public Hearing(int id)
    {
         ID = id;
    }

    public void SetOutcome(int outcomeId, int outcomeNoteId)
    {
        OutcomeID = outcomeId;
        OutcomeNoteID = outcomeNoteId;
    }
}
```

With that, your code could be changed to something like:

```
Hearing hearing;
if (string.Equals(isStandardFlag, "STANDARD", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    hearing = centreSession.StandardHearing;
else
    hearing = centreSession.NonStandardHearing;

hearing.SetOutcome(
    disciplineSvc.SaveResultA(hearing.ID, OffenceID, Outcome),
    disciplineSvc.SaveResultB(hearing.ID, txt1.Text, "ResultHearing"));
```

Some additional notes:

1. I have also changed `string.Compare() == 0` to `string.Equals()`, because I think it expresses the intent better.
2. Some of the names are quite bad (e.g. `txt1` or `SaveResultA`), you should improve those.
3. Dealing with ids a lot is not very object-oriented. I think it would make more sense to deal directly with `Outcome` and `OutcomeNote` objects, not just their ids.